# visual studio code is not launching in linux even though it is in the path

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

visual studio code is not launching in linux even though it is in the path

I tried "code ." and expect to open the vscode for the current folder

Comment: export DISPLAY=:0 made my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export DISPLAY=:0 made my day

My Display was not set.It was unset while doing other debugging. reverting it make the window app launch from terminal.

DISPLAY is part of your linux serverx, usually the linux terminal doesn't support launching the window applications from terminal until the display is configured. so it is essential to make sure you have the right config for your DISPLAY arg for your serverx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).